# Why are there ghost items in my podcast list that I cannot delete?

Tags: iphone, podcasts, macos

Check out the image below.
I cannot finger swipe to the right to get rid of the top and bottom grayed out podcasts.
They are not in iTunes on my local disk or listed in the podcast section of the iPhone under iTunes.
How can I get rid of them?
Forcing a sync doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-download the offending podcast then delete it.